# How can I open other screens into the react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, routes, react-navigation

I'm trying to learn better react-native. In this case I have an issue, with createMaterialTopTabNavigator I can implement a navigation and that works rights, but in this case I have a tab bar with 4 icons. But in this project I have a lot of screens and I can't load those in this tab bar and if I add those screens in this tab this will shown 15-20 icons. this is my code to create navigation :

```js
const NavigationRoutes = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Add: { screen: Add },
        Settings: { screen: Settings },
        List: { screen: List }
    },
    {
        swipeEnabled: true,
        tabBarPosition: "bottom",
        tabBarOptions: {
            showIcon: true,
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "#ccc"
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: "#333"
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "crimson"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

So if I create an external navigation, like this :

```js
const OtherScreens = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Form: { screen: Form },
        Gallery: { screen: Gallery }
    }
);
```

Then, for example: How can I add OtherScreens to NavigationRoutes and load Form screen into Settings that is in the NavigationRoutes ?!

Normally, I can load screens in the NavigationRoutes by:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')
```

But I've problem to load external screen and above code not works in this case.

Thanks

Comment: The question is very confusing, can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @SGhaleb OK :-)
I've a simple App that has 15 screens. The main screens are Home, List and Add. So, logically I can't show each 15 items into that nav bar and I should load external screens and with a trick open other tabs. for example: I've not Settings into tab bar but I've need to load that screen after press on one button into the Home screen. My main problem is, How can I open other screens with props. Like this is default mode: this.props.navigatio.navigate('List')

Comment: @SGhaleb For example check this url, I've create a screenshot: 
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8334915618/question.jpg

Comment: You want to open a screen when you click a button that is not in the tab bar? Also, you should add that screenshot to your question.

Comment: @SGhaleb yes but this case is different, in the main root(createMaterialTopTabNavigator) I've only 4 screens and those links show in nav bar right. but I've need to open other screens in the main route(createMaterialTopTabNavigator). did you understand the question ?

Comment: So you want to connect your other screens inside your tab navigator (main route)?

Comment: @SGhaleb Yes, I've 5 navigation and I have need to connect all of those

Answer (score 0):

You will need to nest the StackNavigator inside the tab navigator.

`const OtherScreens = createStackNavigator( { Form: { screen: Form }, Gallery: { screen: Gallery } } );`

Like this

`Other:{screen :OtherScreens}`

And add it to `NavigationRoutes`

`const NavigationRoutes = createMaterialTopTabNavigator( { Home: { screen: Home }, Add: { screen: Add }, Settings: { screen: Settings }, List: { screen: List }, Other:{screen :OtherScreens}, { swipeEnabled: true, tabBarPosition: "bottom", tabBarOptions: { showIcon: true, style: { backgroundColor: "#ccc" }, labelStyle: { color: "#333" }, indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: "crimson" } } } );`

Comment: So can I access to other screens with the code ?
this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherScreen');

Comment: Inside Other, you can access `Form` and `Gallery `. Basically anything inside `OtherScreens` stack navigation

Comment: Ok, but how can I disable Others tab into material tab navigation ?

Comment: Others tab is a screen, if you disable it you cant use its navigation. Instead you should change `Home: { screen: OtherScreens }` now in your `Home` tab you can access the form and gallery.